# Access Apple TV Infrared Sensor Programmatically

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

Is it possible to access the Apple TV infrared sensor programmatically? (preferrably in Swift)

I would like to perform certain actions based on specific IR codes from a third party remote in my application.

Thanks!